# Angular 2: Toggle sub menu (similar to jQuery slideToggle)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to toggle a sub menu within a list when a link is clicked.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZoOGJD8FUbBfPgHTKlPh?p=preview

**Template**

```
<ul>
        <li><a><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Home</a></li>

        <li>
            <a (click)="toggleNavigationSub($event)">Profile</a>
            <ul [@toggleHeight]="navigationSubState">
                <li><a>Settings</a></li>
                <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="toggleNavigationSub($event)">Messages</a>
            <ul [@toggleHeight]="navigationSubState">
                <li><a>Notifications</a></li>
                <li><a>Private</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I have 2 sub menus inside last 2 `li` tags. I was able to create slideToggle animation using Angular2 Animations but I'm having trouble properly implement it.

**Animation**

```
animations: [
        trigger('toggleHeight', [
            state('inactive', style({
                height: '0',
                opacity: '0'
            })),
            state('active', style({
                height: '*',
                opacity: '1'
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('200ms ease-in')),
            transition('active => inactive', animate('200ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
```

**Function**

```
navigationSubState: string = 'inactive';
toggleNavigationSub(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.navigationSubState = (this.navigationSubState === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive');
}
```

When I toggle the animation by clicking the `a` tag, all of the sub-menus are toggling at the same time. How can I limit the toggling for the sub menus which are only subjected to the click?

Comment: This is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your animations for both menus were being hooked up to the one variable controlling the state, `navigationSubState`, they were all being affected by every toggle action.

Instead, change the single string property to a map from menu name to string, and only toggle that menu item.

Here is the [forked Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MTTvk1UBrUSvDbxsBGxx?p=preview), and the relevant code is below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ul>
        <li><a><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> Home</a></li>

        <li>
            <a (click)="toggleNavigationSub('Profile', $event)">Profile</a>

            <ul [@toggleHeight]="navigationSubState.Profile">
                <li><a>Settings</a></li>
                <li><a>Privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a (click)="toggleNavigationSub('Messages', $event)">Messages</a>

            <ul [@toggleHeight]="navigationSubState.Messages">
                <li><a>Notifications</a></li>
                <li><a>Private</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  animations: [
        trigger('toggleHeight', [
            state('inactive', style({
                height: '0',
                opacity: '0'
            })),
            state('active', style({
                height: '*',
                opacity: '1'
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('200ms ease-in')),
            transition('active => inactive', animate('200ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
})
export class App {
  navigationSubState: { [menu: string]: string} = {
    Profile: 'inactive',
    Messages: 'inactive'
  };
  toggleNavigationSub(menuName: string, event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.navigationSubState[menuName] = (this.navigationSubState[menuName] === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive');
    }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain me what's this means navigationSubState: { [menu: string]: string}
I'm new to ng2 and this look strange to me. Thanks

Comment: That is not to do with ng2, it is a Typescript type definition that says "`navigationSubState` is an object whose keys are strings and values are strings". I find being explicit about types helps Typescript catch my errors when I use the wrong type.